# Clam image dataset to an image classification

Tags: data-request

I´m trying to classify images of 3 clam species:

Ruditapes Decussatus 
[image]

Venerupis Pullastra 
[image]

Ruditapes philippinarum
[image]

I've read that you can scrape from Google Images; but as you can see, I do not think that Google's differentiation with respect to these species is reliable enough. And the ton of images to train can be really tedious to separate manually.

Does someone know a dataset that can be used; or a pre-trained network?